# python modules not found when su

Tags: python-2.7, centos7, su

As root I install lots python modules by pip, which work fine.
[python import cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onN4m.png)

Create a new user by `adduser new` with no flags.

I was `su - new` to this account.
After that, Even `pip` is error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/bin/pip", line 7, in 
>       from pip import main
>   ImportError: No module named pip

I think the problem is lost path reference.
which my modules is under

> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages

The os is Centos7, I think i need a answer for how to permantly added the module path.

Thanks.

Comment: sudo pip install should install your pip modules for all users I believe.

Comment: first you need to install pip since you added a new user. after that you need to sudo pip install packagename to install other packages.

Comment: i was installed all needed modules and pip in root, It work fine, But after I switch to the user "new", All modules include pip is not able to use.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Ran into something similar where su broke relative imports with the dreaded "module not found" error